# How can I resolve unresolved reference errors when importing databinding?

Tags: android-studio, data-binding

On MainActivity.kt file, I'm trying to import databinding-related stuff but, the unresolved reference error in bold still remains. I've tried to delete caches and successfully made gradle sync with the required plugins and dependencies as well as dataBindnig tag in android { }.

The problem is now the reference error still remains in bold as below.

```
package com.jisung.airquality

import android.Manifest
import android.app.Activity
import android.content.DialogInterface
import android.content.Intent
import android.content.pm.PackageManager
import android.location.LocationManager
import android.provider.Settings
import android.widget.Toast
import androidx.activity.result.ActivityResultLauncher
import androidx.activity.result.contract.ActivityResultContracts
import androidx.appcompat.app.AlertDialog
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat
import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat
import android.os.Bundle
import com.jisung.airquality.**databinding**.ActivityMainBinding

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    lateinit var binding: **ActivityMainBinding**

    private val PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE = 100

    var REQUIREND_PERMISSONS = arrayOf(
        Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION)

    lateinit var getGPSPermissionLauncher: ActivityResultLauncher<Intent>


    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = **ActivityMainBinding**.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)

        checkAllPermission()
    }
```